# Class + does not exist

Tags: magento2.3, product-attribute, class-not-found

I have this strange error when i try to edit a product or update attributes
I am unable to find anyone else who has had this non specific error[image]

appreciate any help as work flow is frozen

Full error below

```
1 exception(s): Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class + does not exist Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class + does not exist <pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('+') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php:49] #2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('+') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:48] #3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('+', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56] #4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('+', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Validator/UniversalFactory.php:36] #5 Magento\Framework\Validator\UniversalFactory->create('+') called at [vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/AbstractAttribute.php:622] #6 Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\AbstractAttribute->getFrontend() called at [generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Eav/Attribute/Interceptor.php:1168] #7 Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor->getFrontend() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Widget/Form.php:189] #8 Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form->_setFieldset(array(&Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#000000003311021b000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110125000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110119000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110224000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110225000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110118000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110222000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110223000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110127000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110220000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110221000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110126000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#000000003311011a000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110122000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110123000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110124000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110175000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110172000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#000000003311022d000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#000000003311022e000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110173000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#000000003311022b000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#000000003311022c000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110174000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110171000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110169000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110177000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#000000003311023c000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110208000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110168000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#000000003311023f000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110234000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110176000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#000000003311016c000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#000000003311016b000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#000000003311016a000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#000000003311016e000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#000000003311016d000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110164000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110160000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110161000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110162000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110163000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#000000003311016f000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110167000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110166000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110165000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#000000003311015c000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110159000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110235000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110236000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#000000003311015a000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110233000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110294000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110296000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110291000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110292000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#000000003311029e000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#000000003311029f000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110290000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#000000003311029c000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#000000003311029d000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110298000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110299000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#000000003311029a000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#000000003311029b000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#00000000331102a6000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#00000000331102a7000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#00000000331102a4000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#00000000331102a5000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#00000000331102a2000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#00000000331102a3000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#00000000331102a0000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#00000000331102a1000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110297000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#00000000331102ae000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#00000000331102ac000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#00000000331102ad000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#00000000331102af000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#00000000331102b9000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033113e52000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#00000000331102b7000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#00000000331102a8000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#00000000331102a9000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#00000000331102b3000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#00000000331102b5000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110230000000006df184b1#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#0000000033110231000000006df184b1#), &Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset#0000000033110111000000006df184b1#, array('category_ids', 'gallery', 'image', 'media_gallery', 'quantity_and_sto...', 'tier_price')) called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Action/Attribute/Tab/Attributes.php:90] #9 Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Action\Attribute\Tab\Attributes->_prepareForm() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Widget/Form.php:156] #10 Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form->_beforeToHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1096] #11 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1101] #12 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:671] #13 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Action/Attribute/Tab/Attributes/Interceptor.php:648] #14 Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Action\Attribute\Tab\Attributes\Interceptor->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Widget/Tabs.php:492] #15 Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tabs->getTabContent(&Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Action\Attribute\Tab\Attributes\Interceptor#00000000331107a8000000006df184b1#) called at [generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Action/Attribute/Tabs/Interceptor.php:219] #16 Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Action\Attribute\Tabs\Interceptor->getTabContent(&Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Action\Attribute\Tab\Attributes\Interceptor#00000000331107a8000000006df184b1#) called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/widget/tabs.phtml:58] #17 include('/var/www/vhosts/...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:59] #18 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(&Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Action\Attribute\Tabs\Interceptor#00000000331107a1000000006df184b1#, '/var/www/vhosts/...', array('tabs' => array('attributes' => &Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Action\Attribute\Tab\Attributes\Interceptor#00000000331107a8000000006df184b1#, 'inventory' => &Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Action\Attribute\Tab\Inventory\Interceptor#0000000033111997000000006df184b1#, 'websites' => &Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Action\Attribute\Tab\Websites\Interceptor#0000000033111bf7000000006df184b1#, 'tier_prices' => &Amasty\Paction\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Action\Attribute\Tab\TierPrice\Interceptor#0000000033111019000000006df184b1#))) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:271] #19 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/vhosts/...') called at [generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Action/Attribute/Tabs/Interceptor.php:479] #20 Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Action\Attribute\Tabs\Interceptor->fetchView('/var/www/vhosts/...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:301] #21 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Template.php:129] #22 Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1097] #23 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1101] #24 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:671] #25 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Action/Attribute/Tabs/Interceptor.php:804] #26 Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Action\Attribute\Tabs\Interceptor->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557] #27 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('attributes_tabs') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:533] #28 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('attributes_tabs') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206] #29 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('attributes_tabs') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488] #30 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('attributes_tabs', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193] #31 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('attributes_tabs', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585] #32 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('left', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535] #33 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('left') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206] #34 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('left') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488] #35 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('left', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193] #36 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('left', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585] #37 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('side.col', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535] #38 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('side.col') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206] #39 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('side.col') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488] #40 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('side.col', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193] #41 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('side.col', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585] #42 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.main.contai...', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535] #43 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.main.contai...') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206] #44 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.main.contai...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488] #45 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.main.contai...', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193] #46 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.main.contai...', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585] #47 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.content', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535] #48 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.content') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206] #49 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.content') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488] #50 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.content', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193] #51 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.content', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585] #52 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535] #53 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206] #54 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488] #55 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193] #56 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585] #57 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('backend.page', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535] #58 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('backend.page') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206] #59 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('backend.page') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488] #60 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('backend.page', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193] #61 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('backend.page', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585] #62 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535] #63 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206] #64 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488] #65 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193] #66 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:954] #67 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:492] #68 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php:258] #69 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#00000000331136f0000000006df184b1#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php:171] #70 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#00000000331136f0000000006df184b1#) called at [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php:193] #71 Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#00000000331136f0000000006df184b1#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:141] #72 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261] #73 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http#00000000331136f7000000006df184b1#) called at [index.php:39] </pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

Found a simple key stroke error in eav_attribute table frontend_model 
Found the field with a simple + deleted it after backup of sql
Explains why it’s a unique error
Problem disappeared after upgrade and compile

Comment: Such an easy mistake to make. Thanks for the update. Useful for the community.

Answer (score 0):

Try these Commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
chmod -R 777 var pub generated
```

Comment: Tried this method but does not solve issue

Comment: try to clear `var/cache` and `generated` folder manually

Comment: Tried this method but also does not solve problem